# Ethernet socket impedes adding shields

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, ethernet

I just bought a KEYESTUDIO W5500 Ethernet Arduino without realizing that the Ethernet socket on the board impedes adding any additional shields to the device because:

1. Horizontally the socket runs right up next to the shield connector sockets
2. Vertically the socket is a good 1/4 inch higher that the shield connector
   sockets

Is there a good solution for extending the shield connector sockets vertically so that they clear this Ethernet socket?

Comment: what shield do you want to put up? you do not have much free memory for more libraries

Comment: @Juraj The main shield I want to add is a screw terminal I/O card. But it's the mechanical clearance I am concerned about, not the memory

Comment: Reverse the order of the shields: Uno | Terminal I/O | Ethernet?

Comment: @JRobert The board has built in Ethernet - there is no Ethernet shield

Comment: Oops, missed that. Back to extra headers!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug some of these into the Arduino headers to add extra space.

They come in different lengths and can be cut to the required number of pins.

They also come in different pin lengths.

Google `long tailed pin headers`.

[image]

Comment: After googling a bit I found `Arduino Stackable Header Kit` which is more descriptive of what I want.